# Django unittest on_delete CASCADE

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, django-testing, django-tests

I am writing tests for a Django application.

Currently, to test for the cascade deletion, I create instances, delete the parent and assert the child is deleted as well.

Is there a better method to do this, for example retrieve the parameters passed to the `ForeignKey` of the model using `_meta.get_field` ?

Comment: You can get a list of fields with `_meta.get_fields()`, and filter with `instanceof(field, ForeignKey)`, and check the `field.on_delete`. But I find it a bit odd that you test Django functionality. The idea is that you test *your business logic*. Not Django's, since the developers of Django need to ensure that it works correctly.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you. I am testing this in case someone accidently changes the `CASCADE` in the code, they would be alerted when running the test. I am new to testing, is that going too far ?

Comment: not *per se*. Although of course you always should look what you will *gain* from it, what the possible trouble will be, and the amount of *effort* you put in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of fields from a model with `Model._meta.get_fields()`. Then for each field, you can chck if it is a `ForeignKey` (or `OneToOneField`, which is a subclass of a `ForeignKey`) with `isinstance(field, ForeignKey)`, and then obtain the attribute `field.on_delete` to determine what the "parent" will do with the "child" if it is deleted.

So you can for example obtain the names of the fields for which the `ForeignKey` is set to `CASCADE` with:

```
[f.name
 for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()
 if isinstance(f, ForeignKey) and f.remote_field.on_delete is models.CASCADE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's @Willem's answer rewritten as a test function with verbose failure:

```
def test_foreignkey_cascade(self):
    """
    Test all FKs have on_delete=models.CASCADE unless otherwise specified
    """

    for f in self.model_instance._meta.get_fields():
        if isinstance(f, models.ForeignKey):
            self.assertEquals(f.remote_field.on_delete, models.CASCADE,
                              '{} failed, value was {}'.format(
                                  f.name, f.remote_field.on_delete))
```